# How to trigger up/down number input spin buttons in Jest React testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm attempting to test using `@testing-library/react` & `@testing-library/jest-dom` a number input component and I haven't figured out how to test triggering the up/down spin buttons of the input.

```
test("renders and updates NumberInput", () => {
   let value = "5";
   const setValue = (e) => value = e.value;

   render(<NumberInput
     label="Quantity"
     name="quantity"
     value={value}
     onChange={setValue}
     step={0.5}
     min={0.05}
   />);

   let element = screen.getByRole('spinbutton');
   expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();

   fireEvent.change(element, { target: { value: "10" }});

   expect(value).toEqual("10");
});
```

How could I test triggering the up/down spin buttons?

Comment: If you're trying to simulate a click why are you using `fireEvent.change`? Also note it's probably better to use `@testing-library/user-event`, and if this is a wrapper around `input[type="number"]` re-testing browser functionality probably isn't valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't figure out how to simulate clicking the buttons, I did figure out how to test the `step` and `min` props working with the `userEvent.keyboard`. This triggers the up/down events of an input which in my case is the same as clicking the up/down spin buttons.

```
userEvent.click(element).then(() => {
   expect(element).toHaveFocus();

   userEvent.keyboard('[ArrowDown]').then(() => {
      expect(value).toEqual("9.5");
   });
});
```